# Trigger which should delete a row after an update operation doesnt work properly

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

hi there i'm trying to learn mysql, however, after i define a trigger which should work after an update operation over a column in a table, it doesnt work properly. It should delete a row instantaneously whenever i update this column.(this column's type is DATE and it declared to NULL at the beginning). this is my structure of table

```
Create Table Projects (

    pro_ID INT NOT NULL,
    pro_Name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    comp_date_info DATE DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(pro_ID)
);
```

and i try to add a tuple with a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_into_Projects ( IN projectID INT, IN projectName VARCHAR(50) )
BEGIN

INSERT INTO homework.Projects values (projectID, projectName,NULL);

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and this is the calling statement for adding a new tuple into Projects Table

```
call insert_into_Projects(111,'Project Mayhem');
```

so far, as you can realize i have a tuple like

```
   pro_ID   pro_Name         comp_date_info

1) 111      Project Mayhem   NULL
```

and this is the trigger implementation

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_Projects_update
AFTER UPDATE ON homework.Projects
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

delete from homework.Projects
where comp_date_info != NULL;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Finally i want whenever i update this tuple's comp_date_info into a proper date value trigger should delete it.

```
update homework.Projects
set comp_date_info = '1989-04-05'
where pro_ID = 113;
```

But i'm facing with an error which says

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'Projects' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

i will appreciated if you can help and by the way thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a row you've called a trigger on (obviously).

Instead, define the column as `NOT NULL`, which forces the application code to deal with the situation, in this case to delete the row rather than update it with a null in the column.

The other option is to bundle all the logic into a stored procedure that you you pass in the new values and the stored procedure can either update or delete based on the input.

Comment: but is the first way logical ? because i guess i should give a value which is not null and then i must update it to NULL ?